# python & sqlite - Bind parameters when multiple columns with same name are present

Tags: python, sqlite

I have the following update query:

```
UPDATE table1 SET name = ?, surname = ?, birth_date = ?, sex = ? WHERE name = ? AND surname = ?
```

I'm running this query through the `sqlite3` python package, and specifically using this method:

```
    def _connect_and_execute(query, data=None):
        conn = None
        try:
            conn = sqlite3.connect(DB_FILE_PATH)
            cur = conn.cursor()
            if data is None:
                cur.execute(query)
            else:
                cur.execute(query, data)
            conn.commit()
        except sqlite3.Error as e:
            logging.error(e)
            raise e
        finally:
            if conn:
                conn.close()
```

`DB_FILE_PATH` is a constant which holds the path to the sql file. The method is called by using the above query as `query` parameter and the list `["John", "Johnson", "01/01/2000", "M", "John", "Johnson"]`.

The query executes without errors, but without actually changing the values in the database (check through a database explorer software and with other select queries). Obviously the corresponding record to update already exists.

I did a little search on the internet and my hypothesis for this behaviour is that the `name` and `surname` columns are referenced twice for bind parameters. To my understanding, what this [page states](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html) is that it is possible to bind values by using the corresponding indexes. I tried to update the query to:

```
UPDATE table1 SET name = ?1, surname = ?2, birth_date = ?3, sex = ?4 WHERE name = ?5 AND surname = ?6
```

but the behaviour is still the same.

Is it possible to bind parameters to the same columns twice? Is that the problem in my case? If so, which can be a possible solution?

Comment: Do you actually want to *change* ("John", "Johnson") to ("John", "Johnson")?

Comment: yes, those two columns are used as "ids" to retrieve the correct row, the interest is mainly in changing the other columns. But it may also happen that I want to also change name and surname, for instance if there are typos.

Comment: Your code is ok. If you don't see any changes this means that either there is no row in the table with ("John", "Johnson"), or the new values are the same as the existing ones or you are examining a different database/table.

Comment: This code should do what you want.  Duplicate values in the data is not the problem.  The problem must be something else.  Perhaps the input arguments are not as shown, or perhaps some other function is being called instead of this one, or you're checking the wrong table afterwards, or one of a million other possible errors...

Comment: As a basic first debugging step, print `query` and `data` at the top of the function.  This will at least confirm that those arguments are as you expect, and that the function is actually being called.

Comment: I see that you have `logging.error(e)` in the except block.  Did you check the log to look for this error?

Comment: Thank you for the check of the code. Probably is the late hour but I still don't see any change when the query is executed. I will check in more details other possible causes of the issue.

Comment: no error catched, the query executes fine. I also printed the query and the data while debugging and they looks fine to me. Maybe I will update the question with the actual data, not the sample ones that I used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found where I was wrong. The problem was not in the update query, but in the values of the parameters that I passed to be bound. Indeed, they contain numbers, but I passed them as integers and not as strings. By casting them to string I solved the problem.

I also checked that both queries in the question are working properly, there's no need to specify the parameter indexes even if the same column is referenced multiple times.